# If $f$ is $C^1$ then $f^{-1}$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppous that $f:V \rightarrow W$ and $f^{-1}:V \rightarrow W$ is its inverse with $V,W$ open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to know if $f$ is $C^1$ implies $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

if someone finds that $f^{-1}$ is $C^1$ or differentiable it would be much better

Comment: Is the co-domain of $f^{-1}$ correct ? If derivative of $f$ at some point in domain is non zero then refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: @YadatiKiran Don't you mean that if $Df$ is *never* singular, then the Inverse Function Theorem implies that $f^{-1}$ is also differentiable, and hence, continuous?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou: Yes. If it is non singular at a point say $a$ then the inverse is continuously differentiable in some neighbourhood of $a$

Comment: Note, though, that $n=1,$ $V=W=(0,1)$ and $f(x)=x^3$ shows that you cannot hope for $f^{-1}$ to be differentiable in general.

Comment: Whoops, I meant $V=W=(-1,1),$ of course.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou so it doesn't tell me anything about the continuity of $f^{-1}$

Comment: @BrancoFloresRocha I'm not completely sure: If $n=1$, again, then $f$ needs to be monotone, and then, $f^{-1}$ is monotone, but then, $f^{-1}$ is automatically continuous, since otherwise, $f$ wouldn't be surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f: V \to W$ is $C^1$ and bijective, so $f^{-1}: W \to V$ exists where $V,W \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ are open sets.

The [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) theorem tells us (only using continuity of $f$) that $f^{-1}$ is indeed continuous.

We cannot hope in general for $f$ to be differentiable, as $f(x)=x^3$ on $\Bbb R$ shows, but if $f'(a) \neq 0$, we will have differentiability at $f(a)$ by the inverse function theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "yes". If you know a priori that $f$ is a bijection, then a mere continuity of $f$ is sufficient, no need to assume that $f$ is $C^1$. This result is called the [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) theorem.